# How to configure Keycloak to make custom totp field in token url?

Tags: java, security, token, keycloak

I'm trying to set up a token from keyloak and using custom totp. I've been looking at options like: https://medium.com/@mesutpiskin/two-factor-authentication-via-email-in-keycloak-custom-auth-spi-935bbb3952a8 and https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator. Unfortunately these solutions are not quite what I was looking for. They all offer totp for authentication in the keycloak itself without getting a token. I need to implement TOTP so I can put it in the "totp" field on the url with the token (http://localhost:8082/auth/realms/gilgamesh/protocol/openid-connect/token). I've been surfing the internet for 2 days but haven't found anything. Could you please tell me how to do it?